# How frequently is the expression "when it comes to" used in spoken English?

Tags: colloquial-language, idiomatic-language

If I want to tell my friend about some topics, such as what I do in my free time or my favorite movies, is it appropriate to use "when it comes to" at the beginning of the conversation?

For example, "When it comes to my favorite movies, ..."

Does the expression normally be used in spoken English?
If it is not normally used or too formal, please advise me what expression I should use :)

Comment: usually “when it comes to” is used to talk about how something is handled differently than usual.  “I usually don’t eat beets but when it comes to Elizabeth Faulkner’s beets, I’d eat them anytime.

Comment: Or, I only buy pre-owned DVDs but when it comes to my favorite movies, I’ll pay for brand new Blu-rays.

Comment: Or, Dan doesn’t know much about diesels but when it comes to steam engines he wrote the book on them.

Comment: It is used quite frequently but, in my opinion, only in the context of an existing conversation and an existing topic within that conversation. If it was used to start or redirect a conversation it would sound odd. Also I can't think of a time I would use it wthout an element of sub-classification being involved. The previous comments all have that (beets, DVDs and railway locomotives are main classifications while the Faulkner brand, pre-owned and new DVDs, and diesel and steam locos are sub-classifications).

Comment: @BoldBen - I can't see any problem with "When it comes to my favourite movies, I would pay for brand new Blu-rays, but normally I would only buy pre-owned DVDs".

Comment: @Chris Absolutely. DVDs as a whole are the category, the pre-owned ones and the new Blu-rays are two sub categories. However, I wouldn't expect someone to say "When it comes to DVDs..."  at the start of a conversation, or to redirect a conversation from cars, beer or politics, I'd expect them to say something like "Do you buy DVDs?" or "What do you think of Blu-ray, is it worth the money?": although it might be appropriate to say "When it comes to DVDs..." to move a conversation from audio media to DVDs because that could be seen as a related topic.

Comment: @BoldBen - How about "When it comes to DVDs I would only by them pre-owned but I would pay for brand new Blu-rays for my favourite movies"?  I don't have a problem with this sentence.  Do you?

Comment: Or switching the sentence around you could say "When it comes to Blu-rays, I would buy them brand new and only for my favourite movies, but with DVDs I would buy them pre-owned".

Comment: Very true, Chris. I hadn't thought of that usage. However I would say there's still an element of classification and sub classification because you're talking about domestic movie media. If you were to say "When it comes to Blu-rays, I would buy them brand new and only for my favourite movies" without the bit about pre-owned DVDs the sentence would be incomplete unless it was in the context of other people's expressed opinions.